# Persistent jupyterlab page on web browser

Tags: windows, jupyter, jupyter-lab

In linux, there can be dedicated jupyter lab port that is always available. User does not need to launch Jupyter Lab from terminal.

How can something similar be achieved in windows. So that even if I restart my machine I still can visit the page and expect jupyter lab to be running.

Kindly note I don't want to use jupyter-lab desktop instead.

Basically I want a bookmark saved and when I open the page it automatically triggers a live jupyter lab workspace as is the case in linux ports.

Comment: You could use Google Colab environment rather than running your own server

Comment: You can configure JupyterLab to use specific port, but you probably already know this (since you mention running a service with a fixed port on Linux). In that case the question just becomes how to auto-start a process of choice on Windows, which might depend on the version of Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably in Linux kernel based OS, JupyterLab is converted to a service. You can check all services with `systemctl --type=service --state=active` command. In Windows, if you want a similar experience to enabled services of a Linux kernel based OS, you can easily create a new startup item. To do that:

1- Create a shortcut with the command that you use to start JupyterLab:

a. Right click to an empty part of your desktop -> New -> Shortcut

[New shortcut creation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5IaC.png)

b. Write `"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" /k <terminal_command_for_jupyterlab>` to shortcut's location.
[JupyterLab command shortcut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSS6M.png)

This shortcut will run the command for JupyterLab. Give an appropriate name to your shortcut.

2- Add this shortcut to startup items:

a. Press `Win`+`R` buttons.

b. Write `shell:startup` to Run window.

c. Copy your shortcut and paste your shortcut to folder that is opened with previous step.

After all these steps, JupyterLab should be started automatically without user interaction on each startup of Windows.